# pass an object from a form to another.Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, object, parameter-passing

I have form1 and there is a class Events inside form1.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  { 
  public class Events
    {
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public int Event { get; set; }
        public string DisplayPbp { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public List<int> Change { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Events> events = new List<Events>();
```

I also have a second form2 and I want to be able to add an object Event from the second form to first form1 .Here is the second form2 code

```
      public partial class Form2 : Form
      {
      Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        List<int> Change = new List<int>();                
            for (int i = 0; i < Playinglist.Count(); i++)
            {
                Change.Add(Playinglist[i].Key);
            }     
      form1.events.Add(new BasketballApp.Form1.Events()
            {
                Time = string.Format("{0}:{1}", 10, 00),
                PlayerId = 0,
                TeamId = game.HomeTeamId,
                Event = 22,
                DisplayPbp = "Change",
                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
                Change = Change                    
            });
```

This is not passing the new object to form1.Any suggestion?

Comment: And what error do you get? Is the class Events an innerclass (Defined within form 1) or outside?

Comment: you've place 
public List<Events> events = new List<Events>(); 
outside of Events class but your are using it in form2 as 
games.events.add(blah blah);
move above line inside your class and then try again

Comment: the class Events is (Defined within form 1).In the line Form1.events.Add(new Events() there is an error : System.ComponentModel.Component.Events is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: I also move above line inside class and then try again but is not pass the object

Answer (score 0):

According to the error it using the wrong `Events` class: `System.ComponentModel.Component.Events`

You should prefix it with your namespace (or use a different name for `Events`)

In Form1:

```
public List<YourNamespace.Events> events = new List<YourNamespace.Events>();
```

In Form2:

```
form1.events.Add(new YourNamespace.Events()
{
    Time = string.Format("{0}:{1}", 10, 00),
    PlayerId = 0,
    TeamId = game.HomeTeamId,
    Event = 22,
    DisplayPbp = "Change",
    X = 0,
    Y = 0,
    Change = Change                    
});
```

Comment: Is the Events class in the same namespace? If it's declared within Form1 then not. You should then Use YourNamespace.Form1.Events.